# exporting log from cloudwatch to s3 using create_export_task not missing some logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to export past 15mins access logs that are in cloudwatch to S3 bucket however when run it, it succesfully store logs into S3 however missing lots of logs. for example in cloudwatch past 15mins, there are 30 logs and in S3 it only has about 3 logs.

```
group_name = '/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-env/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
log_file = boto3.client('logs')

now = datetime.now()
deletionDate = now - timedelta(minutes=15)

start = math.floor(deletionDate.replace(second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp()*1000)
end = math.floor(now.replace(second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp()*1000)

destination_bucket = 'past15mins-log'
prefix = 'lambda2-test-log/'+str(start)+'-'+str(end)
# # TODO implement
response = log_file.create_export_task(
                logGroupName = group_name,
                fromTime = start, 
                to = end, 
                destination = destination_bucket,
                destinationPrefix = prefix
            )
if not response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
    raise Exception('fail ' + str(start)+" - "+ str(end))
```

In the documentation it says it is an asynchronous call, my guess is since there are 3 servers where I get logs from, that is causing the problem?

Thanks in advance.